# How to assert that a given compiler option is set to a given value VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor

I'm doing something dependent upon the code being compiled with `/fp:precise`

I've never encountered this situation before... but is there a way to test that a given compiler option is set in a particular way and error at compilation time if not for VS2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to assert what the settings are, I'd use the [`float_control` pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45ec64h6.aspx) to tell the compiler to use the setting you need. I believe the syntax should be something like this:

```
#pragma float_control(push)
#pragma float_control(precise, on)

// your code here...

#pragma float_control(pop)
```

Comment: I found that the documentation was wrong... no variation would make it work except the above.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd suggest surrounding those preprocessor blocks with `#ifdef _MSC_VER` / `#endif` for portability.

Comment: @AlexandreC. wouldn't that just hide a compilation error?  Wouldn't it be better to have the compiler complain on another compiler, forcing the coder to figure out the issue, the solution, on that compiler?

Comment: @Mordachai: If you are worried about this, use `#else\ #error "blah blah"`. Compilers may ignore pragmas they don't understand.

Comment: @AlexandreC: Not just "may" (§16.6/1): "Any pragma that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored."